# Utilizar lapply (em substituição a for) para deixar apenas as colunas em comum de vários dataframes em uma nova lista

Tags: r, lapply

`dput` da lista:

```
structure(list(col1 = structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 1:5, c = 1:5), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), col2 = structure(list(
    a = 6:10, c = 6:10), .Names = c("a", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame"), col3 = structure(list(a = 11:15, 
    c = 11:15), .Names = c("a", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), 
    col4 = structure(list(a = 16:20, b = 16:20), .Names = c("a", 
    "b"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), col5 = structure(list(
        a = 21:25, c = 21:25), .Names = c("a", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", 
"col3", "col4", "col5"))
```

A única coluna comum entre eles é `a`.

Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
newlist<-lapply(1:length(list),function(x)colnames(x))
```

Mas é retornado `NULL`.

Também tentei utilizar `merge` (com lapply) para agregar estes dataframes (considerando `all=TRUE,by='row.names',incomparables=NA,sort=FALSE`), mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o pacote `plyr` para juntar a lista original em um data frame:

```
library(plyr)
res <- ldply(dados, data.frame)
```

`res` é um data frame com 3 colunas: `a`, `b` e `c`. Como `b` e `c` não estão presentes em todas os elementos de `dados`, eles possuem `NA`. A função `select_if` do `dplyr` permite que selecionemos apenas as colunas de `res` tais que todos os elementos não sejam `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- res %>%
  select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
```

Agora basta separar o `res` sem `NA` utilizando a função `split`. Ela vai separar todas as colunas que não sejam a coluna `.id` em uma nova lista:

```
split(res[, -1], res$.id)
```